# How to write few characters if font doesn't have them?

Tags: css, fonts

It's kinda hard for me to describe the problem.
But anyway - I got my font which I load using `@font-face`, everything is 'ok' until the numbers appear (my font doesn't support numbers). So my question is, if I got my text fe. "Hello 3 World", is there any chance for making "Hello" and "World" using my own font and the numbers using any other like Arial?

Comment: oh boy. The way I see it you need to add a separate class to all numbers and if you don't want to do it manually then do it via jquery.. do you need a sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get stuck an alternative is cufon

http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/

You can actually specify custom characters should you need them.